# How to indent input controls for a nested HTML list using CSS to a single column

Tags: css, list, input, indentation

I have a nested html list, with each element having a set of associated input controls. I want to indent all the input controls to a single column. An example is given below

```
[b][b][c]  • Element_1
[b][b][c]     • Element_1.1
[b][b][c]        • Element_1.1.1
[b][b][c]        • Element_1.1.2
[b][b][c]     • Element_1.2
[b][b][c]  • Element_2
[b][b][c]  • Element_3
```

Here [b] means a button and [c] means a checkbox and • means a bullet sign for the following element.

Comment: Just a thought, but if you *show your HTML* then we can (probably) give better answers. And, that way, we don't need to have a key to understanding your diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following HTML (please, in future *show* your HTML, diagrams are less useful than you might think for communicating mark-up, though they're great for showing the desired end-result):

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="controls">
        <button>b</button>
        <button>b</button>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>Element_1
        <ul>
            <li><span class="controls">
        <button>b</button>
        <button>b</button>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>Element_1.1
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="controls">
        <button>b</button>
        <button>b</button>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>Element_1.1.1</li>
                    <li><span class="controls">
        <button>b</button>
        <button>b</button>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>Element_1.1.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class="controls">
        <button>b</button>
        <button>b</button>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>Element_1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span class="controls">
        <button>b</button>
        <button>b</button>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>Element_2</li>
    <li><span class="controls">
        <button>b</button>
        <button>b</button>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>Element_3</li>
```

Then the following CSS seems to do as you wish:

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 6em;
}

ul ul {
    position: static;
    margin-left: 0;
}

li {
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

span.controls {
    position: absolute;
    width: 6em;
    right: 100%;
}

span.controls * {
    display: inline;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JhzwU/).

Comment: Thanks. I would take care to add my markup as well in future.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; and that will be much appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:list-item;` for your `input` to achieve this effect.

Comment: I do not want to add bullet in front of `input` controls. I just need them to be aligned in a single column irrespective of the indentation of the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the mark-up you could just separate them out into individual lists:

```
<ul>
    <li>Element_1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Element_1.1</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Element_1.1.1</li>
                    <li>Element_1.1.2</li>
                </ul>    
            <li>Element_1.2</li>
        </ul>
    <li>Element_2</li>
    <li>Element_3</li>
</ul>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/asjaC/)